# JAVA AVL Deletion, how to implement using existing rotation code?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

It's been 3 days and I still cannot fix my problem, my problem is that my code for delete does not work perfectly every time I delete. I have this existing code from D.S. Malik's book which titled "Data structures in Java". I wanted to implement the delete operation but it fails most of the time when I use the existing rotation code, the complete program is listed below:

```
public class AVL
{
protected class AVLNode
{
    public int info;
    public int bfactor;
    public AVLNode llink;
    public AVLNode rlink;
}

protected AVLNode root;
protected bool isTaller;
private bool isDuplicate = false; 

private AVLNode rotateToLeft(AVLNode root)
{
    AVLNode p; //reference variable to the root of the right subtree of root 
    if (root == null)
        throw new Exception("Error in the tree.");
    else if (root.rlink == null)
        throw new Exception("Error in the tree: No right subtree to rotate.");
    else
    {
        p = root.rlink;
        root.rlink = p.llink; //the left subtree of p becomes the right subtree of root 
        p.llink = root;
        root = p;   //make p the new root node 
    }

    return root;
}

private AVLNode rotateToRight(AVLNode root)
{
    AVLNode p;  //reference variable to the root of the left subtree of root 

    if (root == null)
        throw new Exception("Error in the tree.");
    else if (root.llink == null)
        throw new Exception("Error in the tree: No left subtree to rotate.");
    else
    {
        p = root.llink;
        root.llink = p.rlink; //the right subtree of p becomes the left subtree of root 
        p.rlink = root;
        root = p;    //make p the new root node 
    }

    return root;
}

private AVLNode balanceFromLeft(AVLNode root)
{
    AVLNode p;
    AVLNode w;

    p = root.llink;   //p points to the left subtree of root 

    switch (p.bfactor)
    {
        case -1:
            root.bfactor = 0;
            p.bfactor = 0;
            root = rotateToRight(root);
            break;
        case 0:
            throw new Exception("Error: Cannot balance from the left.");
        case 1:
            w = p.rlink;
            if (w.bfactor == -1)
            {
                root.bfactor = 1;
                p.bfactor = 0;
            }
            else if (w.bfactor == 0)
            {
                root.bfactor = 0;
                p.bfactor = 0;
            }
            else if (w.bfactor == 1)
            {
                root.bfactor = 0;
                p.bfactor = -1;
            }

            w.bfactor = 0;
            p = rotateToLeft(p);
            root.llink = p;
            root = rotateToRight(root);
            break;
    }

    return root;
}

private AVLNode balanceFromRight(AVLNode root)
{
    AVLNode p;
    AVLNode w;

    p = root.rlink;   //p points to the right subtree of root 

    switch (p.bfactor)
    {
        case -1:
            w = p.llink;
            if (w.bfactor == -1)
            {
                root.bfactor = 0;
                p.bfactor = 1;
            }
            else if (w.bfactor == 0)
            {
                root.bfactor = 0;
                p.bfactor = 0;
            }
            else if (w.bfactor == 1)
            {
                root.bfactor = -1;
                p.bfactor = 0;
            }
            w.bfactor = 0;
            p = rotateToRight(p);
            root.rlink = p;
            root = rotateToLeft(root);
            break;
        case 0:
            throw new Exception("Error: Cannot balance from the right.");
        case 1:
            root.bfactor = 0;
            p.bfactor = 0;
            root = rotateToLeft(root);
            break;
    }

    return root;
}

private AVLNode insertIntoAVL(AVLNode root, AVLNode newNode)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = newNode;
        isTaller = true;
    }
    else if (root.info == newNode.info)
        isDuplicate = true;
    //throw new Exception("No duplicates are allowed."); 
    else if (root.info > newNode.info) //newNode goes in the left subtree 
    {
        root.llink = insertIntoAVL(root.llink, newNode);

        if (isTaller)             //after insertion, the subtree grew in height 
            switch (root.bfactor)
            {
                case -1: root = balanceFromLeft(root);
                    isTaller = false;
                    break;
                case 0: root.bfactor = -1;
                    isTaller = true;
                    break;
                case 1: root.bfactor = 0;
                    isTaller = false;
                    break;
            }
    }
    else
    {
        root.rlink = insertIntoAVL(root.rlink, newNode);

        if (isTaller)              //after insertion, the subtree grew in height 
            switch (root.bfactor)
            {
                case -1: root.bfactor = 0;
                    isTaller = false;
                    break;
                case 0: root.bfactor = 1;
                    isTaller = true;
                    break;
                case 1: root = balanceFromRight(root);
                    isTaller = false;
                    break;
            }
    }

    return root;
    } 
}
```

From the book I followed all instructions for creating the delete method but as I said it failed.

Edit: Ok so this is my delete method, but actually it is coded in C# pardon me for the additional calls to the unknown method since I am currently developing an AVL animation app in C#, but anyways I already removed those but if you see some unrelated method calls just ignore it.

```
public Node deleteFromAVL(Node parent, Node delNode)
    {
        if (parent == null) //not found
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item not found.");
            isShorter = false;
        }
        else if (parent.value.Equals(delNode.value)) //found
        {
            //the four cases of deletion
            #region FOUR CASES OF DELETION
            if (parent.left == null && parent.right == null) //leaf node
            {
                isShorter = true;
                return null;
            }
            else if (parent.left == null)
            {
                isShorter = true;
                tempNode = parent.right;
                return tempNode;
            }
            else if (parent.right == null)
            {
                isShorter = true;
                tempNode = parent.left;
                return tempNode;
            }
            else
            {
                current = parent.left;
                trailCurrent = null;
                while (current.right != null)
                {
                    trailCurrent = current;
                    current = current.right;
                }
                parent.value = current.value;

                if (trailCurrent == null)
                {
                    parent.left = current.left; //movement
                    if (parent.left != null)
                    {
                        parent.left.moveToParent(); //move to parent
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    trailCurrent.right = current.left; //movement
                    if (trailCurrent.right != null)
                    {
                        trailCurrent.right.parent = trailCurrent;
                    }
                }

                isShorter = true;
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else if (parent.value > delNode.value) // search left
        {
            parent.left = deleteFromAVL(parent.left, delNode);
            //change balance factors
            if (isShorter)
            {
                switch (parent.bfactor)
                {
                    case -1: parent.bfactor = 0;
                        isShorter = true;
                        break;
                    case 0: parent.bfactor = 1;
                        isShorter = false;
                        break;
                    case 1: parent = balanceFromRight(parent);
                        isShorter = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else//search right
        {
            parent.right = deleteFromAVL(parent.right, delNode);
            //change balance factors
            if (isShorter)
            {
                switch (parent.bfactor)
                {
                    case -1: parent = balanceFromLeft(parent);
                        isShorter = false;
                        break;
                    case 0: parent.bfactor = -1;
                        isShorter = false;
                        break;
                    case 1: parent.bfactor = 0;
                        isShorter = true;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        return parent;
    }
```

Comment: where is your delete method? at least put it up so we can give you ideas or show you how to fix itg

Comment: Ok so I added the delete method above, have a look...

Answer (score 0):

I will just show you my implementation of my node removal.

```
private AVLNode<T> Remove(AVLNode<T> T, int x)
{
    if(T == null){ //if the value does not exist just return null
        return null;
    }                
    if(x < T.item)//if the value is less than item 
    { 
        if(T.left == null)//if T.left = null return null x doesnt exist
        { 
            return null;
        }
        else
        { 
            T.left = Remove(T.left, x); //T.left exists recursive call Remove with T.left
            T.height = Math.max(Height(T.left), Height(T.right))+1;//reset height
            if(HeightCheck(T.right) - HeightCheck(T.left) == 2){ //check for imbalance
                if(T.right.left.height > T.right.right.height){ //if the height of the subtree is imbalance
                   return T = DoubleRotateWithRightChild(T); //if after delete the right->left > right->right double rotate
                }                        
                else{
                   return T = SingleRotateWithRightChild(T); //if after delete right->left < right->right single rotate
                }                                                  
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(x > T.item){ //if X > item 
            if(T.right == null)\
            { //having an issue dealing with null pointers being passed so deal with it here
                return null; //if T.right == null return null
            }
            else
            {
                T.right = Remove(T.right, x); //if T.right exists recursive call remove with T.right
                T.height = Math.max(Height(T.left), Height(T.right))+1; //rest height
                if(HeightCheck(T.left) - HeightCheck(T.right) == 2)
                { //check for imbalace
                    if(T.left.left.height > T.left.right.height)
                    {
                       return  T = DoubleRotateWithLeftChild(T); //if after delete left->left height > left->right height double rotate
                    }                           
                    else
                    {
                       return T = SingleRotateWithLeftChild(T); // if after delete left->left height < left->right height single rotate
                    }                            
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if((T.right != null) && (T.left != null)){ //if x == T.item and both left and right exist
                T.item = FindMax(T.left).item; //find the max item in the left sub tree or the right most value of the left subtree and set it as the new subtree root item
                T.left = Remove(T.left, T.item); //remove the value you just made the new subtree root from the left subtree
            }
            else
            {
                if(T.left != null){ //if only one side exists return it.
                    return T.left;
                }                            
                else
                {
                     return T.right;
                }                          
            }
        }
    }
    return T;
}
```

hope my implementation helps you understand where yours is misstepping.
mainly where I see it is the implementation of the rotations you are not using any double rotations.  This is a double rotation with the right child.  as from my code above you will see when it needs to be used.

```
private AVLNode<T> DoubleRotateWithRightChild(AVLNode<T> T)
{
    T.right = SingleRotateWithLeftChild(T.right);
    return SingleRotateWithRightChild(T);
}
```